# Change the color of rows in DataGridView with certain conditions using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I want to change color of rows of DataGridView with condition.
When i add two row that have same value error me :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Detail 
Name Of :
DataGridView : dgv_ListZamen
Table : tbl_TedadZemanat
Columns : TedadZemanatRasmi , TedadZemanatPimankari

```
private void pictureBox_ben_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if(dgv_listZamen.RowCount != 0)
            {
            var query = db.tbl_TedadZemanats.Where(c => c.TedadZemanatRasmi.Value + c.TedadZemanatPimankari.Value > 2).ToList();

                string a = query.Select(c => c.Id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                dgv_listZamen.Rows[b].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Well, what is the value of `b` and why do you expect it to always be valid?

Comment: As a precaution, you should be checking 'a' at the very least because FirstOrDefault() can give you either an expected value or a NULL which could lead to an unexpected failure later on.

Comment: The error tells you whats wrong... the index you are fetching is an ID not an index and doesn't work as index as its out of range